# Downloading progress restarts when app goes to background windows phone 8.1 (Universal App)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am developing a universal app and here I am downloading a zip file of 50 MB and few images simultaneously. while downloading if the app goes to background then the download progress of the zip file starts from zero again. This problem appears only in release mode. Here I am using BackgroundDownloader to download files and Here is the link to download my project.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pfz3wiggtofhjlr/HubApp1.zip

The problem appears only when the zip file and images are downloading at the same time.

Any Help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called ***Windows Runtime Component***, If you open 
   **Package.appxmanifest**. Click on the **Declarations** tab, there you will see an ***ListView*** with the title

***Avalible Declarations:***  You will see a button which says **Add**.

Under these controls you will see an ***ListBox*** with the title ***Supported Declarations:*** .

Click on the ***ListBox***, there you will see different alternatives. Select the declaration

***Background Task***, click on the **Add** button.

After you've done that, you'll get an ***Description*** about the prefrences that needs to be set by your desired events. There from i wan't you to check this link out and fully understand it! [Click Here](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/04/04/windows-phone-8-1-a-universal-background-task.aspx)

I hope you perceived my answer, Rate this comment and Good Luck!